# MeteorJS allow injection of anchor tag

Tags: meteor, javascript-injection

I have a basic chat that reads from a database. Each chat message is read from the database by this.

```
<span>{{formatChat text}}</span>
```

text being the message read.
And then I use the formatChat registerHelper to detect URLs.

```
Template.registerHelper('formatChat', function(text) {
  var urlRegex = /https?:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)((([a-zA-Z0-9\?\=\/])+)?((\#|\?)(.+)?)?)?$/
  var urlRegexMini = /(www(\d{0,3})\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)(\.(com|net|org|gov|co\.uk|edu|io\b)+)([a-zA-Z0-9\?\=\/]+((([a-zA-Z0-9\?\=\/])+)?((\#|\?)(.+)?)?)?)?$/
  finalString = "";
  //Parse every word individually
  split = text.split(' ');
  for (i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    finalString += " ";
    if (urlRegex.test(split[i])) {
      finalString += "<a href='" + split[i] +  "'>" + split[i] + "</a>";
    }
    else if (urlRegexMini.test(split[i])) {
      finalString += "<a href='http://" + split[i] + "'>" + split[i] + "</a>";
    }else{
      finalString += split[i];
    }
  }
  return finalString.substring(1,finalString.length);
});
```

The problem is that meteor doesn't allow injection, so it will literally show the anchor tag as plain text.

One solution that I thought of was to have a registerHelper for each individual word, but that seems rather foolish.

How can I efficiently get around this rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should do it:

```
{{{formatChat text}}}
```

Comment: Yes this worked, for anyone in the future reading, this will allow all injections to go through, so be aware of that. My best solution for that is to add

    .replace('<','&lt;').replace('>','&gt;');

to the end of the string, which replaces all < and > less than or greater than signs, which will not parse as html code.